# Format output bash script in PHP's popen

Tags: php, bash

In my PHP script I'm executing a bash script with popen() and I output the response. But the response has a different encoding, and I don't know how to convert it.

I tried to convert it to utf8 but no results. Also tried to set the locale to nl_NL.utf8.

PHP function:

```php
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen("$cmd 2>&1 ; echo Exit status : $?", 'r');

$live_output     = "";
$complete_output = "";

while (!feof($proc))
{
    $live_output     = fread($proc, 4096);
    $complete_output = $complete_output . $live_output;
    echo "$live_output";
    @ flush();
}

pclose($proc);
```

Example response:

```
[2K[1A[2K[G
[2K[1A[2K[G⠋ load plugins
[2K[1A[2K[Gsuccess load plugins - 0.975 s
⠋ load plugins
```

This should be just:

```
success load plugins - 0.975 s
```

The ⠋ thing is a loader which is moving. Could that be the problem? Or are these characters the colorcode of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are `ANSI Escape Sequences`, they are not bash commands but console commands used for coloring output or replacing/updating output on a single line.

Often commands offer a `—no-color` flag.

Also, a environment variable exists for common commands: `NO_COLOR`.
Here's a list of common flags/variables to disable colored output => https://no-color.org/

Otherwise, you could always filter the output with a regex: `/(\x9B|\x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -\/]*[@-~]/`

Comment: Thanks. In this case it's not the coloring but modifying the current line (the loader indeed). A regex replace will do fine for now :)